# Realm for react native not working in debugging mode

Tags: reactjs, react-native, realm, realm-js

When opening react-native app in debug mode i receive the following error in console and device connected via usb

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try downgrading to realm version 2.16.2. Your problem has been reported by some users in [this issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/2088).

Comment: Yes Thanks!!, I was able to run it after downgrading.